# Is this bad form for a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want to make a while loop that checks the nearest power of two and returns that power of two. the function works for all values except for the case where the target is 1. Is there a better way to format this without using an if statement?

```
def power_of_two(target):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Determines the nearest power of 2 greater than or equal to
    a given target.
    Use: power = power_of_two(target)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        target - value to find nearest power of 2 (int >= 0)
    Returns:
        power - first power of 2 >= target (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    x = 0
    count = 0
    while target > x:
        count += 1
        x = 2**count
    if target == 1:
        count = 1
    else:
        count = 2**count
    return count
```

Ive tried changing the value of count but I cant think of a better way

Comment: If you want to do it without `while` you can return just `2 ** (len(bin(number)) - 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to track `count` since you're returning the number, not the exponent you need to get there:

```
def power_of_two(target):
    x = 2
    while x < target:
        x = x * 2
    return x
```

`while` is an implicit `if` bound to a loop. Here you just start with `2` and keep multiplying it by 2 until you're past your target. You could start with `1`, as well, though it's a little harder to describe the bounds there. It also doesn't tell you what exponent you end up using - but you were throwing out that information anyway.

Comment: This seems to fail when

Comment: @user3542203 Not sure you finished your message...?

Answer (score 0):

If at all you want the result for smaller numbers, ok, you can do it with loop. In case if the target number consists of say some 15 digits or something, How long it will take for the loop to execute?

To do this there is a better method where no loop is involved.

```
def power_of_two(target):
    import math
    pwr = math.log(target)/math.log(2)
    pwr = math.floor(pwr)
    return 2**pwr

#case 1:
r = power_of_two(1500)
print(r)
#output: 1024

#case 2:
r = power_of_two(15564387909876345642500)
print(r)
#Output :9444732965739290427392
```

The idea behind this: When we want to know what power of number A gives B, The only way to find out is taking log on both sides. For eg.,

```
'''
A**x = B

If we have to find out x, we take log on both sides:

log A**x = Log B
x* log A = log B (Since log A**x = x log A)
x = log B / log A 
'''
```

Hope this will be helpful